# JSON.parse not working with escaped quotes

Tags: javascript, json, escaping, quotes

The following code is throwing an error:

```
alert(JSON.parse('{"name":"Quick Write  \"English\"","category":"qwer"}'));
/*
{
    "name": "Quick Write  \"English\"",
    "category":"qwer"
}
*/
```

It says

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 23

How do I make escaped quotes work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use double \ instead of \

```
let x = '{"name":"Quick Write  \\"English\\"","category":"qwer"}';
console.log(JSON.parse(x));
```

Comment: Yes! I forgot that what I type doesn't directly become a string. The first slash is taken as a modifier and is removed.